# Applying filters to nested components

Tags: i18next, react-i18next

I'm trying to apply a custom filter (for adding properly inflected suffixes in Turkish) using the `<Trans>` component and interpolation. The problem is that a key part of the sentence that needs to be inflected (the name of a user), is rendered by its own component. Is there a way to conditionally apply a filter to a nested component?

- I can't directly use the inflection filter on the inner component. The inner component is used in multiple places, and each context may need different filters or none at all.
- The inner component just gets a user id as a prop, and fetches its own contents (the user's name) through react-redux. The outer component (which owns the sentence context), has no idea about the contents of the inner component.
- The filters are useful for a single language (Turkish). The filter to be used must be part of the translation file, as all other languages will **not** use those filters. (Also, choosing a filter is the job of the translator)

---

Practically it would help if I could do something like that (but that doesn't work)

```
{  // en.json
   newMessage: "You got a new message from <1>user</1>" 
}

{  // tr.json
   newMessage: "Size {{<1>user</1>, ablative_suffix}} yeni bir mesaj geldi" 
}
```

Which I wish would render something like *"Size **Mert'ten** yeni bir mesaj geldi"* given the user name "Mert". Is there another way to accomplish something like this?

---

### `<User>`

```js
const User = ({ user }) => <strong>{user ? user.name: null}</strong>;

const mapStateToProps = (state, { id }) => ({ user: state.users[id] });

export default connect(mapStateToProps);
```

### `<NewMessage>`

```js
export const NewMessage = ({userId}) => 
    <Trans i18nKey="newMessage">
        You got a new message from <User id={userId}/>
    </Trans>;
```

Comment: did this works? `Size <1>{{user, ablative_suffix}}</1> yeni bir mesaj geldi`

Comment: @felixmosh No. The nested component is `<User id={userId}/>`. It fetches the actual name from the redux store without being aware of i18n. 

I can make `<User>` translatable, but then I need a way to pass a translation context to it, which may be different everywhere it is used, for every language.

Comment: I've debugged Trans component which is the one that allows to render react components, and seems that it takes the "children" of the component from the translations, that means that if your component generates it's children, it won't be able to access it.

If you desperately need it, you can write your own custom Trans component.

Comment: Can you pls provide a sample component of `User`?

Comment: @felixmosh here you go. The inner component gets its content from redux, that's the tricky part.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this solution, https://codesandbox.io/s/react-i18next-2w5c2.

I'm extracting the `children` on the User component (hacky way) and add it as special value `_1_children`, then, use it translations, which `Trans` will inject it as `children` to the component, therefore, there is `children || 'data'` as the children of `User` component.

From all of my attempts, looks like there is not "clean" way to do so, I think that it is better to connect to the redux store by your self (you have the `id`) and pass the user name as variable like I did.

Anyway, i18next `Trans` component supports only injecting data from translation to Component and **not vice versa**.